# How do we pass or propagate data backwards through the Navigation stack in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

```
                1.FlatButton(
                onPressed: () async {

                    var typedName=await Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return CityScreen();
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                  print(typedName); //prints the value of cityName
                }

               2. FlatButton(
                 onPressed: () {
               Navigator.pop(context, cityName);
              },
```

The no.1 is coming from file loading_screen and no.2 is coming from city_screen. Can you anyone help me understand what is happening that when you pass a variable or anything in the pop? And when come that onPress method is still working because the the method Navigator.push has been already assigned to the variable but still that method Navigator.push is working when I pressed the button?Does that onPress doesn't care about the variable TypedName and just looks for the method Navigator.push?

Comment: I wanted to know how is that onPressed method in no.1 is working when the method Navigator.push is assigned to the variable and we messed up the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use push method it will create the new screen over your current page and pop will remove last screen, you cannot pass name with both, you can check basics of navigation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics), if you want to pass name to next page you should use something like pushnamed method and you can see the logic of passing name [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes). And for all methods you should check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html#static-methods).

Comment: I know that but isn't it that pop has another argument called result (whose type is future for push) which you can pass through pop to the previous route?

Comment: nope pop only remove current screen you want to push name also you can use popAndPushNamed method. There is much more explanation about methods in here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31